# How to select using input form?

Tags: input

Let us assume that we have the list with some names, say

```
list = {"Name1","Name2","Name3"};
```

How to make a graphical interface allowing to set the value of the parameter `parameter` to be equal to one of the values from the `list` by just clicking on the corresponding value of `list`?

**Update**

Following comments by kglr, I provide the example piece of code that would contain the choosing interface:

```
list ={"Name1","Name2","Name3"};
SetterBar[Dynamic[parameter], list]
If[parameter=="Name2",16,"False"]
```

Since the code that follows after `SetterBar` is not delayed until I make some choice in the setter bar, it does not work properly: the `If` condition evaluates for the value of `parameter` that is not associated with the choice.

[image]

Comment: `SetterBar[Dynamic[parameter], list]`?

Comment: @kglr : if this command is placed inside the code, then the code below it does not wait for the choice of `SetterBar` but is evaluated instead. Is it possible to postpone the code evaluation until the choice has been made?

Comment: can you update your question with an example  illustrating the situation in your comment?

Comment: @kglr : I have added the example.

Comment: dou you get what you need if you replace the third line with `Dynamic@If[parameter === "Name2", 16, "False"]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something modal, the easiest is probably ChoiceDialog:

```
list = {"Name1", "Name2", "Name3"};
parameter = ChoiceDialog["Choose a name.", list];
If[parameter == "Name2", 16, "False"]
```

Or even simpler if parameter was just a temporary variable:

```
list = {"Name1", "Name2", "Name3"};
If[ChoiceDialog["Choose a name.", list] == "Name2", 16, "False"]
```

Or even simpler--get rid of the If:

```
ChoiceDialog["Choose a name.", {"Name1" -> False, "Name2" -> 16, "Name3" -> False}]
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you please tell me how to avoid some graphical issues like the one shown in the plot from the update to my question (the options do not fit the window)?